# Convertir imagen a base64 para visualizarla en una vista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

A través de un web api estoy obteniendo la ruta de una imagen almacenada en el servidor. La ruta es un string que convierto a un array de bytes para luego convertirlo en una imagen en base64. Cuando visualizo la imagen en la vista, no arroja ningún error pero no carga ninguna imagen. No encuentro donde tengo el error.

CODIGO:

```
// Por cada registro que obtengo, transformo el campo "adjunto" (ruta de la imagen) en arreglo de bytes
    private MisTurnos MapearAMisTurnosDesdeRegistro(Registro registro)
    {
        return new MisTurnos
        {
            Codigo = Convert.ToInt32(registro["numero"]),
            Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(registro["fecha"]),
            Hora = registro["hora"].ToString(),
            Servicio = registro["servicio"].ToString(),
            Sucursal = registro["sucursal"].ToString(),
            Estado = Convert.ToInt32(registro["estado"]),

            // Esta propiedad es la que utilizo para guardar la imagen
            Orden = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(registro["adjunto"].ToString())
        };
    }


// Por cada registro que obtuve del web api con la ruta de la imagen correspondiente
// transformada en arregl ode bytes, transformo ese arreglo en base64
    private IEnumerable<MisTurnosViewModel> ConvertirOrdenEnImagen(IEnumerable<MisTurnosViewModel> listaTurnos)
    {
        foreach (var item in listaTurnos)
        {
            item.OrdenImagen = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(item.Orden);
        }

        return listaTurnos;
    }
```

Por último, en la vista, muestro en un tag  la propiedad OrdenImagen, que contiene la imagen transformada a base64:

```
<img src=@item.OrdenImagen />
```

Comment: que valor tiene `src` si das click a  inspecionar elemento ?

Comment: Revisa el tu etiqueta `img`, ya que aquí la expones de esta forma `<img src=@item.OrdenImagen />` cuando debería estar de esta manera `<img src="@item.OrdenImagen" />` solo faltan comillas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para convertir una imagen en una string codificado podes usar algo como esto:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Convierte una imagen en una cadena de texto
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Path">Ruta la la imagen</param>
    /// <returns>cadena de texto</returns>
    private static string Conversor(string Path)
    {
        byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path);
        string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
        return base64ImageRepresentation;
    }
```

Supongamos que en el modelo tenemos obtenemos el valor de la imagen:

```
    public string Imagen64
    {
        get
        {
            return "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";
        }
    }
```

Para mostrarla en la vista podes usar:

```
      @{
        var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", Model.Imagen64);
      }
        <p>Imagen es:</p>
        <img src="@imgSrc" />
```

Comment: Gracias, con este ejemplo fácil y claro lo pude solucionar!